# Extract substring from Text column

Tags: powerbi

Column 1(data)                       Column 2(what the goal is)
Max Pink, Peter Orange, Marc Blue         Max Pink

How to obtain column2 with DAX function?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDIQX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split column by delimiter and choose leftmost delimiter in the option if you want only the first value https://www.tutorialgateway.org/how-to-split-columns-in-power-bi/